# Javascript Class Clarification

Tags: javascript, class

Please go through the code

```
function Item()
{
this.state = 0;
}

Item.prototype.SendRequest = function()
{
  //some request callback returns and calls GotResult
  var that = this;
  {
  that.GotResult();//used 'that' because its inside another block
  }
}

Item.prototype.GotResult = function()
{
  //add to local db with callback which calls AddedToLocalDb
  var that = this;
  // Here is where the problem is
  {
  that.AddedToLocalDb();//..... ERROR
  }
}

Item.prototype.AddedToLocalDb = function()
{
}
```

On the "this.AddedToLocalDb()" i get its undefined. Why is that? Any Ideas?
On that block 'this' variable is undefined. Have i made a mistake or is there a scope problem. Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are this is an issue with a callback function and a loss of the `this` value when the callback function is called.  But to know for sure, you'll have to show the actual code involving the callback.  We need to see not just method definitions, but the actual code that is using these methods leading up to the problem.

I suspect it's something you call and pass `GotResult` to.  If that guess is correct, then you can pass `this.GotResult.bind(this)` instead of just passing `this.GotResult` and it will probably solve your problem.

This type of problem can sometimes be worked around with your `var that = this` technique, but that only works when using local functions in that same scope, not with method definitions defined in a sibling scope.

Comment: BTW i added gotresult.bind(that);